# How to check if all arguments are files?

Tags: bash, arguments, test

How do you check if all arguments passed to a shell script are files? I tried to use the `$@` parameter and `-f` with an `if` statement.

Comment: Note that the `-f` operator of the `[` command is to test whether a given file is a _**regular** file_ (after symlink resolution), to the exclusion of any other  type of file (socket, directory, fifo, device...), is that what you want? Or do you want to disambiguate between directory and non-directory files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To test whether *all* arguments are files, it's easier to test whether one of the arguments is *not* a file:

```sh
for argument do
    if [ ! -f "$argument" ]; then
        printf 'Not a file: %s\n' "$argument" >&2
        exit 1
    fi
done

echo 'All arguments are files'
```

This iterates over all positional parameters and tests each one in turn. If a non-file is found, an error is printed and the code terminates.

To investigate all arguments:

```sh
for argument do
    if [ -f "$argument" ]; then
        printf 'Is a file: %s\n' "$argument"
    else
        printf 'Is not a file: %s\n' "$argument"
    fi
done
```

This iterates over all positional parameters and tests each one in turn, printing the result of the test.

Note that "is a file" *actually* means "is a regular file, or a symbolic link to a regular file". If you want to make sure it's not a symbolic link to a regular file, use

```
if [ ! -f "$argument" ] || [ -L "$argument" ]; then
```

as the test in the first loop, or

```
if [ -f "$argument" ] && [ ! -L "$argument" ]; then
```

as the test in the second loop.

The first line of the loop could also be written

```
for argument in "$@"; do
```

... but people tend to forget to double quote `$@`, and the loop at the top is shorter to type anyway.